# Hosting for my webapplication

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, web-hosting

I've worked on a Small Webapplikation in PHP and MySQL in the backend. In the frontend,  there's  website as User interface. Now it's time to make it available on the Internet for usage in the webbrowser. I prefer using a website hosting solution, as Strato offers. In my case, is it better to use some services from Amazon Web Services?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, it looks like what you have is a basic web app that doesn't require anything fancy in terms of hosting, so something like a Starter or Basic hosting package offered by Strato would do for you:

https://www.strato.de/hosting/

If you want to save the hosting fees, you could try the Amazon AWS t2.micro free tire instance (free for one year). However, the instance will need to be setup and configured for hosting your app. If you're comfortable with Linux system admin etc., it could be a great option:

https://aws.amazon.com/free/